# Why did the female space vampire from Lifeforce need a mate?

Tags: aliens, vampire, lifeforce

In [Lifeforce](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089489/) (1985) the female space vampire (aka: [Space Girl](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Girl)) has the power to drive men wild. She drains humans of their life energy but for some reason needed a human mate and my question is:

#### Why did she need a human mate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [transcript](https://subscene.com/subtitles/lifeforce/english/802292);

> "When they take on a new life form they have to learn from that life form.
>
> **Mate with it, in a sense.**"

It seems clear that the intention is less to give the alien (and the human) sexual pleasure and more as a way of learning about the lifeform's genetic structure and physiology. The mating also creates a "[psychic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeforce_%28film%29)" that allows the alien to learn about human culture.

Also it's an excuse for an extended nude scene.